# Clang problem "Small Triangles, Large Triangles" in HackerRank website

Tags: c

I've been trying to solve "Small Triangles, Large Triangles" problem in HackerRank website in C language it is kind of sorting array problem and i used Selection Sort algorithm. My code seems to be working but it works only on some test cases.
this is the task:

> You are given  triangles, specifically, their sides a, b and c. Print them in the same style but sorted by their areas from the smallest one to the largest one. It is guaranteed that all the areas are different.
>
> The best way to calculate a volume of the triangle with sides a,b  and c is Heron's formula.

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct triangle
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

typedef struct triangle triangle;
void sort_by_area(triangle* tr, int n) {
    //Sort an array a of the length n
    int area[n];
    int p[n];
    int temp[3];
    int min;
    double doubledArea[n];
    //calculate the volume
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        // volume = 0.5 * (H * W * L)
        p[i] = (tr[i].a + tr[i].b + tr[i].c) * 0.5;
        doubledArea[i] = p[i]*(p[i]-tr[i].a)*(p[i]-tr[i].b)*(p[i]-tr[i].c);
        area[i] = sqrt(doubledArea[i]);
    }
    //sort by volume
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        min = i;
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
        if(area[j] < area[min])
        {
            min = j;
            temp[0] = tr[i].a;
            temp[1] = tr[i].b;
            temp[2] = tr[i].c;
            tr[i].a = tr[min].a;
            tr[i].b = tr[min].b;
            tr[i].c = tr[min].c;
            tr[min].a = temp[0];
            tr[min].b = temp[1];
            tr[min].c = temp[2];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    triangle *tr = malloc(n * sizeof(triangle));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d%d%d", &tr[i].a, &tr[i].b, &tr[i].c);
    }
    sort_by_area(tr, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d %d %d\n", tr[i].a, tr[i].b, tr[i].c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

when i try for exemple:

```
3
9 8 9 
4 5 7
2 5 4
```

it works, but doesn't work with inputs like:

```
10
67 67 19
3 57 55
33 33 49
61 58 59
23 43 35
48 42 45
23 12 27
41 34 22
26 49 35
63 46 45
```

Comment: `specifically, their sides , and .` There's something missing.

Comment: Now is probably a good time to learn how to use a *debugger*. With a debugger you can step through your code, statement by statement, while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: Also, remember the hackerrank tests are all about covering all *corner-cases*. Some will not be intuitively obvious given the written question and constraints.

Comment: *"The best way to calculate a volume of the triangle with sides a, b and c is Heron's formula":* no, [not really](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula#Numerical_stability). See W. Kahan's [analysis](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/Triangle.pdf) (PDF).

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the result of floating point computations in `int` arrays - that's a mistake, as warned by the compiler:

> conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data

Therefore an area of say `9.2` will not be considered smaller than `9.3` because they are both stored as `9`.

The arrays used during computation should be `double`. So the two arrays

```
int area[n];
int p[n];
```

should be

```
double area[n];
double p[n];
```